# Custom wp_query - I'm getting 'all' post, not the specific post in the query

Tags: wp-query, customization

Get all post from today, that are of post type 'product' and are in the taxonomy of 'productType' as 'Indica' and in the taxonomy of 'locationCity' as 'Los Angeles' -- However, I get 'all' the post with no regards to the query params of the custom taxonomies.

```
// args
$today = getdate();

$indicaArgs = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'productType' => 'Indica', 
        'locationCity' => 'Los Angeles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'date_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'year'  => $today["year"],
                                'month' => $today["mon"],
                                'day'   => $today["mday"],
                            ),  
                        )
);
// The Query
$query1 = new WP_Query($indicaArgs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tax_query` for that. See official documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Try this:

```
$indicaArgs = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'productType' => 'Indica', 
        'locationCity' => 'Los Angeles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'productType',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'indica', // here should be slug
              ),
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'locationCity',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'los-angeles', // here should be slug
              ),
          ),
        'date_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'year'  => $today["year"],
                                'month' => $today["mon"],
                                'day'   => $today["mday"],
                            ),  
                        )
);
```